# Can't find model 'de_core_news_sm' google colab error

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory, seq2seq

I was running this colab:
https://colab.research.google.com/github/bentrevett/pytorch-seq2seq/blob/master/2%20-%20Learning%20Phrase%20Representations%20using%20RNN%20Encoder-Decoder%20for%20Statistical%20Machine%20Translation.ipynb#scrollTo=RkP61K-evK2C.

But I kept having this error.
Could you help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following command

```
!python -m spacy download de_core_news_sm
```

in a cell and then restart the kernel.

Comment: python example should have code blocks

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this command doesn't work in colab. I got sytax error.

Comment: @JuhyunLee I have updated the syntax.